# JPA - EclipseLink make additional SELECT requests for relationships when merging an entity

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, fetch, relationships

I've got a question on a "strange" behaviour when updating an entity with the merge method.

I have an entity "Personne" that have two relationship `(fetch = LAZY)`. I have a HTML form I use to modify only fields of this entity. When saving this entity with the merge method, I see SELECT requests for all relationships.

I don't understand why these SELECTs are done and I would like to avoid them because the data loaded by this behaviour can be "huge".

There it is my entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="personne")
@NamedQuery(name="Personne.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Personne p")
public class Personne implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
private Integer id;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="date_naissance")
private Date dateNaissance;

@Column(length=75)
private String denomination;

@Column(length=75)
private String nom;

@Column(precision=10, scale=2)
private BigDecimal poids;

@Column(length=75)
private String prenom;

@Column(precision=10, scale=2)
private BigDecimal taille;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Contact
@OneToMany(mappedBy="personne", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Contact> contacts;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Log
@OneToMany(mappedBy="personne", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Logs> logs;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to PersonneHasAdresse
@OneToMany(mappedBy="personne", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<PersonneHasAdresse> personneHasAdresses;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to PersonneHasPersonne
@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<PersonneHasPersonne> personneHasPersonnesParent;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to PersonneHasPersonne
@OneToMany(mappedBy="child", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<PersonneHasPersonne> personneHasPersonnesChild;

public Personne() {
}

public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Date getDateNaissance() {
    return this.dateNaissance;
}

public void setDateNaissance(Date dateNaissance) {
    this.dateNaissance = dateNaissance;
}

public String getDenomination() {
    return this.denomination;
}

public void setDenomination(String denomination) {
    this.denomination = denomination;
}

public String getNom() {
    return this.nom;
}

public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}

public BigDecimal getPoids() {
    return this.poids;
}

public void setPoids(BigDecimal poids) {
    this.poids = poids;
}

public String getPrenom() {
    return this.prenom;
}

public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
    this.prenom = prenom;
}

public BigDecimal getTaille() {
    return this.taille;
}

public void setTaille(BigDecimal taille) {
    this.taille = taille;
}

@JsonIgnore
public List<Contact> getContacts() {
    return this.contacts;
}

public void setContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {
    this.contacts = contacts;
}

public Contact addContact(Contact contact) {
    this.getContacts().add(contact);
    contact.setPersonne(this);

    return contact;
}

public Contact removeContact(Contact contact) {
    this.getContacts().remove(contact);
    contact.setPersonne(null);

    return contact;
}

@JsonIgnore
public List<Logs> getLogs() {
    return this.logs;
}

public void setLogs(List<Logs> logs) {
    this.logs = logs;
}

public Logs addLog(Logs log) {
    this.getLogs().add(log);
    log.setPersonne(this);

    return log;
}

public Logs removeLog(Logs log) {
    this.getLogs().remove(log);
    log.setPersonne(null);

    return log;
}

@JsonIgnore
public List<PersonneHasAdresse> getPersonneHasAdresses() {
    return this.personneHasAdresses;
}

public void setPersonneHasAdresses(List<PersonneHasAdresse> personneHasAdresses) {
    this.personneHasAdresses = personneHasAdresses;
}

@JsonIgnore
public PersonneHasAdresse addPersonneHasAdress(PersonneHasAdresse personneHasAdress) {
    this.getPersonneHasAdresses().add(personneHasAdress);
    personneHasAdress.setPersonne(this);

    return personneHasAdress;
}

public PersonneHasAdresse removePersonneHasAdress(PersonneHasAdresse personneHasAdress) {
    this.getPersonneHasAdresses().remove(personneHasAdress);
    personneHasAdress.setPersonne(null);

    return personneHasAdress;
}

@JsonIgnore
public List<PersonneHasPersonne> getPersonneHasPersonnesParent() {
    return this.personneHasPersonnesParent;
}

public void setPersonneHasPersonnesParent(List<PersonneHasPersonne> personneHasPersonnesParent) {
    this.personneHasPersonnesParent = personneHasPersonnesParent;
}

public PersonneHasPersonne addPersonneHasPersonnesParent(PersonneHasPersonne personneHasPersonnesParent) {
    this.getPersonneHasPersonnesParent().add(personneHasPersonnesParent);
    personneHasPersonnesParent.setParent(this);

    return personneHasPersonnesParent;
}

public PersonneHasPersonne removePersonneHasPersonnesParent(PersonneHasPersonne personneHasPersonnesParent) {
    this.getPersonneHasPersonnesParent().remove(personneHasPersonnesParent);
    personneHasPersonnesParent.setParent(null);

    return personneHasPersonnesParent;
}

@JsonIgnore
public List<PersonneHasPersonne> getPersonneHasPersonnesChild() {
    return this.personneHasPersonnesChild;
}

public void setPersonneHasPersonnesChild(List<PersonneHasPersonne> personneHasPersonnesChild) {
    this.personneHasPersonnesChild = personneHasPersonnesChild;
}

public PersonneHasPersonne addPersonneHasPersonnesChild(PersonneHasPersonne personneHasPersonnesChild) {
    this.getPersonneHasPersonnesChild().add(personneHasPersonnesChild);
    personneHasPersonnesChild.setChild(this);

    return personneHasPersonnesChild;
}

public PersonneHasPersonne removePersonneHasPersonnesChild(PersonneHasPersonne personneHasPersonnesChild) {
    this.getPersonneHasPersonnesChild().remove(personneHasPersonnesChild);
    personneHasPersonnesChild.setChild(null);

    return personneHasPersonnesChild;
}
```

And my generic method to update object :

```
public void merge(E obj) {
        EntityManager em = PersitenceManager.getInstance().getEm(this.persistUnit);
        try {
            EntityTransaction t = em.getTransaction();

            try {
                t.begin();
                em.merge(obj);
                t.commit();
            } finally {
                if (t.isActive()) {
                    t.rollback();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
```

Before the UPDATE statement, there is SELECTs for contacts and logs.
Is anybody know why ? Is it a normal behaviour ? If yes, how to avoid it ?

Thanks you very much for any help !

---

Edit 1:

The complete code from all layers (from REST to DAO):

```
@Path("personnes")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public class PersonnesRest {

    private PersonneServices personneServices = new PersonneServices();

    ...

    @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    public Response update(@PathParam("id") Integer id, Personne personne) {
        if (personne == null || !id.equals(personne.getId())) {
            return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }

        this.personneServices.merge(personne);
        return Response.noContent().build();
    }

    @POST
    public Response create(Personne personne) {
        Personne createdPersonne = this.personneServices.persist(personne);
        return Response.created(URI.create("personnes/" + createdPersonne.getId())).build();
    }

    ...

}

public class PersonneServices extends AbstractBasicServices<Personne> {

    public PersonneServices() {
        super(new PersonneDao(), Personne.class, "poi.model");
    }
}

public class PersonneDao extends AbstractBasicDao<Personne> {

}

public abstract class AbstractBasicServices<E> {

    private AbstractBasicDao<E> dao;

    private Class<E> clazz;

    private String persistUnit;

    public AbstractBasicServices(AbstractBasicDao<E> dao, Class<E> clazz, String persistUnit) {
        this.dao = dao;
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.persistUnit = persistUnit;
    } 

public E persist(E obj) {
        EntityManager em = PersitenceManager.getInstance().getEm(this.persistUnit);
        E res = null;

        try {
            EntityTransaction t = em.getTransaction();
            try {
                t.begin();
                res = this.dao.persist(obj, em);
                t.commit();
            } finally {
                if (t.isActive()) {
                    t.rollback();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }

        return res;
    }

// The merge method is the one in first post.

}

public abstract class AbstractBasicDao<T> {
    public T persist(T obj, EntityManager em) {
        em.persist(obj);
        em.flush();
        em.refresh(obj);
        return obj;
    }

    public T merge(T obj, EntityManager em) {
        return em.merge(obj);
    }
}
```

---

Edit 2:

After review, I had (in persistence.xml) the "shared cache mode" to "NONE". It was obvious the entity manager need to reload relationships (silly me...).
So I set it to "Default".

I made the following tests (I reboot the server for each test) :

- (Test 1-1) Create a new entity (persist): INSERT + SELECTs for relationships.
- (Test 1-2) Update the previous entity (merge): UPDATE (no SELECT).
- (Test 2-1) Update an entity (merge): UPDATE + SELECTs for relationships.
- (Test 2-2) Update the same entity (merge): UPDATE (no SELECT).

Does it seem normal ?

---

Edit 3:

I posted the entire Personne entity and I see now my mistake. I put the @JsonIgnore to avoid loading of relationships when querying to display a list of Personne attributes because of the marshalling of relationships. But then the unmarshalling did not set back the indirected lists. I removed the annotations.

I created a wrapper that only contains attributes I need for JAX-RS layer and update fields to the corresponding entity when need an update and there is no more additional SELECT.

Thanks all for your time.

Comment: Have you accessed the contacts and logs lists before merging?  Check if they are populated in a debugger - if they are, then JPA must check that you haven't modified the lists when it does the merge, which requires a database hit.

Comment: Hello Chris, thanks for your reply. No, no access to these lists before merging. I put breakpoints to getters/setters to be sur but no hit. Fields are also null.

Comment: what environment are you running in?  Are you accessing the relationships anywhere, such as in a toString method?

Comment: I'm running the app under Tomcat7. The webapp is made with AngularJS and the REST Webservices with JAX-RS (+Jackson). There is no toString() method in the bean. I also updated the post.

Comment: How are you obtaining the Entity for merging?  Seems like you might not have mapped the collection in JAX-RS so it is not being passed back for the merge -  JPA will need to merge this empty list into an untriggered lazy one, forcing it to be triggered.

Comment: Thanks for your help Chris. I posted the solution in edit 3. It was indeed a mistake with JAX-RS.

Answer (score 1):

**I cannot reproduce this.**
Can you verify right before calling `merge()` whether the following expression **returns false**:

```
((org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectContainer)obj.getContacts()).isInstantiated()
```

(assuming that you have a getter named `getContacts()` which just returns the field `contacts` within your entity class).

**If it returns `false`** then this would be a "strange" behavior which needs to be further investigated.

**If it returns `true`** (which is most probably the case) then this lazy loaded collection **has been accessed before** hence EclipseLink needs to check whether something has changed in the database.
In this case, check which code accesses the collection beforehand (use a breakpoint to figure this out).

Comment: Hello MRalwasser. I cannot try the whole expression because the obj.getContacts() returns null. There is no proxy for fields, that is strange.

Comment: Can you post/link the complete source of the entity Personne?

Comment: I put the whole entity in my post. I see the solution by doing it and explain why. Thanks for your help !